# Does table aliasing with "as" keyword affect the data type?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, database, casting

I used the below query:

```
select id from foo order by id DESC limit 1
```

to return the last `id` used.

I had in my application something to add plus one if it wasn't zero. It was working fine. But I decided to do this in the sql instead of the C# code. But when I do this:

```
 SELECT IF(id = 0, 0, id + 1) as id from foo order by id DESC limit 1
```

But I get a `System.InvalidCastException` error and to my surprise the data type printed in below code is int64. But did it changed?

Here's the c# code:

```
public int GetLastID()
        {
            using (MySqlConnection con = Open())
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT IF(id = 0, 0, id + 1) as id from foo order by id DESC limit 1";
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();

                    MySqlDataReader data = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    if (!data.Read())
                        return 0;

                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(data["id"].GetType().ToString()); // output: int64
                    return (int)data["id"];
                }
            }
        }
```

Don't blame my bad mysql. I don't use it much. If you know any way better to do this, please tell me!

Comment: It's not the `as`, it's the `if` expression.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, the query will give 2 rows, Query will return values no issues with that ----------> mysql> select IF(id=0, 2,id+3) as ID from test order by id asc limit 2;
+----+
| ID |
+----+
|  4 |
|  5 |
+----+

Comment: @chandran - curious, why would his query give two rows if he has "Limit 1"

Comment: It's not the `as`, and it's not the `if`...  it's the integer addition operation that returns BIGINT. This behavior is documented in the MySQL Reference Manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alias assigned to the column (**`AS id`**) does not change the datatype.

The datatype of the expression is the result of the expression.

In MySQL, an integer addition operation (e.g. **`id + 1`**, where id is integer type) results in `BIGINT`.

This behavior is documented in the (readily available) MySQL Reference Manual here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/arithmetic-functions.html

excerpt:

---

> - The usual arithmetic operators are available. The result is determined according to the following rules:
>
> In the case of `-`, `+`, and `*`, the result is calculated with `BIGINT` (64-bit) precision if both operands are integers.

---

So, the return of `BIGINT` datatype (64-bit integer) is expected behavior.

If your requirement is to return a 32-bit integer, the only workaround (that I know of) is to create a user-defined function, e.g.

```
  DELIMITER $$

  CREATE FUNCTION udf_bigint_to_int(n BIGINT)
  RETURNS INTEGER
  BEGIN
    RETURN n;
  END$$

  DELIMITER ;
```

As a demonstration that this works, and also as a warning about the behavior, passed in a value larger than can be supported by a 32-bit integer, we can run this:

```
  SELECT udf_bigint_to_int(9876543210+9)
```

returns the maximum value for a 32-bit integer:

```
  udf_bigint_to_int(9876543210+9)
  -------------------------------
                       2147483647
```

If the intent is to get the largest `id` value from the table, and add 1 to it, and return that as a 32-bit integer, after creating the user-defined function, you could use a query like this:

```
 SELECT udf_bigint_to_int( MAX(id) + ABS(SIGN( MAX(id) ))) AS id FROM foo
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are wanting to get the next id or last id, but have the function return a zero or a one if the table is empty.  This will give you the last inserted id without you having to write the code.  It is a built in function:

```
select last_insert_id();
```

or, if you need to do it for a specific table, and not the last table you inserted into just now, then this will give you the highest id + 1, or just 1 if the table is empty:

```
select ifnull(max(id),0) + 1 from mytable
```

This just says - give me the maximum id, but if that is null (table is empty), then give me a zero.  Then whichever of those two comes back, add 1 to it.  Or if you want to start from zero, then do:

```
select ifnull(max(id) + 1, 0) from mytable
```

Using max(id) is much better than selecting the first row by descending orde - much more efficient.  Of course, much better to use autoincrement and let the database assign the next id, if what you are trying to do is to assign an id to the next record you are going to insert.

Comment: I'm  using already auto increment, the point is that I need to show this id right the form is loaded and this is before any insert. In that case `last_insert_id()` doesn't helps so I'll use `max()` approach. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Direct answer: No, aliasing won't change your data type, it'll change the name displayed for the column returned by the query